# Why Richtext content is not searchable in hygraph/graphcms?

Tags: next.js, graphql, headless-cms, graphcms, hygraph

Im try to search content from the query user requested but hygraph not showing the result it only show data if title contains it...

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
const { query } = context;
const { posts } = await hygraph.request(
    `
      query BlogPostPage($search: String! ){
            posts(where:{_search: $search}){
            createdAt
            id
            slug
            titile
            coverPhoto {
                url
            }
            content {
                html
            }
            author {
                name
                avtar {
                url
                }
            }
        }
      }
    `,
    { search: query.q }
);

return {
    props: {
        posts,
    },
};
```

}

i want this search query search the query from all the field how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Hygraph currently does not support full text search. From the documentation https://hygraph.com/docs/guides/content/searching-for-content

> Hygraph does not support Full Text Search currently. Rich Text or JSON is currently not supported. Also, it’s not possible to filter or search for references (content relations), multi-value fields, colors as well as coordinates.